# How to merge names with common elements in list?

Tags: python, regex, list, loops, iteration

In a list called 'common', I have a bunch of names that have common elements. For instance, my list has these names in it

```
common = ['Jeremy Paul', 'Paul Stevens', 'John Jordan', 'Jordan Smith', 
'Jordan Walker', 'Walker Marshall']
```

I want to be able to merge all the names that have common elements in the most Pythonic way (don't want to have to use libraries or list comprehension unless necessary). The common elements are the ones that are first names in one string and last names in the following string. As an example, this is what I want the result to be:

```
result = ['Jeremy Paul Stevens', 'John Jordan Smith', 'John Jordan Walker', 
'Jordan Walker Marshall']
```

I only want to have three words in each string, so no `John Jordan Walker Marshall` or anything with more than three names.

Is there some way I can do this in Python? I'm assuming I need to use some loop or form of iteration to go through each item in `common`, or maybe I have to use regular expressions to achieve the desired result. I'd appreciate any pointers in the right direction, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An approach: Split each string up into constituent parts, pair up parts of every item, and check if the first pair ends with the first part of the second pair -- if so insert into a list.

Something like:

```
>>> common = ['Jeremy Paul', 'Paul Stevens', 'John Jordan', 'Jordan Smith', 
... 'Jordan Walker', 'Walker Marshall']
>>> parts = [x.split() for x in common]
>>> [" ".join([x[0], x[1], y[1]]) for x in parts for y in parts if x[1] == y[0]]
['Jeremy Paul Stevens', 'John Jordan Smith', 'John Jordan Walker', 'Jordan Walker Marshall']
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! If you don't mind, can you explain what the advantage of using list comprehension here is? I'm still trying to learn how to nest a loop inside a loop with list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative attempt.

```
In [6]: b = [i.split() for i in common]
In [7]: [' '.join(x[0])+' '+x[1][-1] for x in [b[n:n+2] for n in range(0, len(b), 2)]]
Out[7]: ['Jeremy Paul Stevens', 'John Jordan Smith', 'Jordan Walker Marshall']
```

Concept : Group them in 2 elements and joined then with using some conditions.